# Older versions of manuals

Tags: manual, version-support

Emacs manuals (such as the [Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/elisp.html) are provided at a `.../emacs/manual/<manual-name>.html` URL. Surprisingly, the version number that the manual applies to is not part of the URL.

As I understand it, Emacs-specific manuals are versioned alongside Emacs itself (e.g. there is an Emacs Lisp Reference Manual for Emacs 24.5, one for Emacs 25.0, etc.). **Where can older manuals be found**? The [Emacs download mirror](http://open-source-box.org/emacs/) contains a single Emacs Lisp reference from 2002.

I think it'd be a good idea for the `.../emacs/manual/<manual-name>.html` site to always refer to the newest manual, but for older version to be available at `...emacs/<version-number>/manual/<manual-name>.html`.

Comment: The idea has already been suggested in http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2016-01/msg00079.html and people agree with it. We just need someone to do it.

Comment: I agree, but... Are you looking for arbitrary older manuals, or just the manual for the version(s) of Emacs that you're actually using? Because you already have the latter available inside Emacs (and the indexed & searchable info manuals are considerably better than the html versions).

Comment: Yeah...I know the manual is available through Emacs (and is especially convenient to use through a tool like [helm-info](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/master/helm-info.el)), but I still find myself reaching for the web version. Info files are great, but not for long stretches of reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any official archive. Some very old versions (up to 21.2) are in the [old-gnu directory](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/emacs/).

Most versions since 21.4 (as well as a few [older ones](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/elisp-manual/)) are availble in the [Debian snapshot archive](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/?cat=e), in the package `emacsNN-non-dfsg` ([22](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/emacs22-non-dfsg/), [23](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/emacs23-non-dfsg/), [24](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/emacs24-non-dfsg/), [25](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/emacs25-non-dfsg/)). The file `emacsNN-non-dsfg_VERSION.orig.tar.gz` contains the sources, and the file `emacsNN-non-dsfg_VERSION_all.deb` contains the info file.

Not all systems support deb files out of the box. They can be extracted on Debian and derivatives with `dpkg -L …`. In Emacs, you can open them with `deb-view.el` from the [Debian emacs-goodies compilation](https://alioth.debian.org/scm/viewvc.php/?root=pkg-goodies-el). On a Unix command line, use `ar p ….deb data.tar.xz | xzcat | tar -xf -` (replace `.tar.xz | xzcat` by `.tar.gz | zcat` for older versions) (`ar` is part of the `binutils` collection).